# Is it fine to turn off tcp window scaling and tcp timestamps on server?

Tags: linux, tcp

Our application  is running on Amazon server and we were continuously facing the issue related to tcp handshaking. Sometimes we were not able to connect to our application or telnet on port 80 of our server.
I googled and found the solution that by disabling tcp window scaling and tcp timestamps can solve the problem. I did it and issue got resolved.

Here is the solution : [Why would a server not send a SYN/ACK packet in response to a SYN packet](https://serverfault.com/questions/235965/why-would-a-server-not-send-a-syn-ack-packet-in-response-to-a-syn-packet)

Now, Is this fine to disable tcp window scaling and timestamp on server ? If not then how I'll solve my issue( Handshaking issue ).

Comment: Your question was answered in the answers to the question you linked to (and their reference links).

Answer (score 1):

It's "fine" to turn off both, but there might be drawbacks.

Window Scaling allows the scaling of the advertised window to values greater than 64 kilobytes. If your path has a bandwidth delay product in either direction (smallest bandwidth times the round trip time) larger than 64 kilobytes, you will need to use Window scaling to be able to reach higher bitrates.

Timestamps can help for example in some cases against spurious retransmissions or sequence number wraparound for example. Usually not critical, but as always "it depends.." :p