# Troubleshooting steps when the server not responding to some SYNs

Tags: linux, tcp

What are the troubleshooting steps that I can take if I see that my Linux server does not respond to some of the SYNs that are being sent to it? (I know this from PCAPs that I recorded on my server)
I see 2 possible solution here: [Why would a server not send a SYN/ACK packet in response to a SYN packet](https://serverfault.com/questions/235965/why-would-a-server-not-send-a-syn-ack-packet-in-response-to-a-syn-packet)

1. Disabling TCP timestamps
2. Disable recycling of TIME_WAIT

Does anyone have any additional checks / solutions?